# Laravel - How to resolve unexpected syntax error in payload

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project I have this code:

```
$payloads = [
   'first_name' => $clientdata['first_name'],
   'last_name' => $clientdata['last_name'],
   'other_name' => $clientdata['middle_name']
];

if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id']) {
   payloads['dept_code'] = $clientdata['department_id'];
}

$employee = HrEmployee::updateOrCreate([
            'employee_code' => $clientdata['staff_id'],
        ], $payloads);
```

I have this error:

> Syntax error
>    unexpected:    {
>    after: )

Then this line of code is underlined:

> ```
> if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id']) {
> ```

When I replace:

```
if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id']) {
```

with

```
if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id'])) {
```

it now underlines this:

> payloads['nav_dept_id'] = $clientdata['department_id'];
>
> Syntax error
>    unexpected:    =
>    after: ]

How do I get it wrong and how do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` - `if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id'])) {` and a `$` - `$payloads['dept_code']`

Comment: `$payloads[...]` not `payloads[...]`

Comment: Use a proper code editor that helps you to review your syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
if(!isset($clientdata['staff_id'])) {
    $payloads['dept_code'] = $clientdata['department_id'];
}
```